# passing custom variables to formstone

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I'm using formstone drag and drop file upload in my ajax powered form. using $(".uploadImage").upload("start") and $(".uploadDocs").upload("start") for initializing upload section for image and document separately after ajax function response. Each function working but I want to pass a custom variable, something like folder name to formstone and create a folder with that name and upload image and doc to that folder. how to do that?

Ajax function in which the insertion happens and return the id

---

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: base_url + 'innovation/addProcess',
 dataType: "html",
 data: $('#add_innovation').serialize(),
 success: function(result) {

    var res = result.split("#");
    if (res[0] == 'success') {
       $(".uploadImage").upload("start",postData: {"ideaId":10});// sending custom value to formstone, which is not working as of now
       $(".uploadDocs").upload("start",postData: {"ideaId":10});
     } else {   
        showNotification('alert-danger', result);
     }

    },
     error: function(error) {
        console.log('error');
     }
 });
```

Formstone initialization

---

```
Formstone.Ready(function() {

  $(".uploadImage").upload({            
    maxSize: 1073741824,
    beforeSend: onBeforeSend,
    autoUpload: false,
    //postData: {"ideaId":50} // this is working. but don't want this here
  }).on("start.upload", onStart)
  .on("complete.upload", onComplete)
  .on("filestart.upload", onFileStart)
  .on("fileprogress.upload", onFileProgress)
  .on("filecomplete.upload", onFileComplete)
  .on("fileerror.upload", onFileError)
  .on("queued.upload", onQueued);

$(".uploadDocs").upload({            
  maxSize: 1073741824,
  beforeSend: onBeforeSend,
  autoUpload: false,
}).on("start.upload", onStart)
.on("complete.upload", onComplete)
.on("filestart.upload", onFileStart)
.on("fileprogress.upload", onFileProgress)
.on("filecomplete.upload", onFileComplete)
.on("fileerror.upload", onFileError)
.on("queued.upload", onQueued);

});

function onCancel(e) {
   console.log("Cancel");
   var index = $(this).parents("li").data("index");
   $(this).parents("form").find(".upload").upload("abort", 
   parseInt(index, 10));
}

function onCancelAll(e) {
  console.log("Cancel All");
  $(this).parents("form").find(".upload").upload("abort");
}

function onBeforeSend(formData, file) {     

 console.log(formData.get("ideaId")); // here i need the posted data. currently its not getting here

 formData.append("ideaId", ideaId);
 return ((file.name.indexOf(".jpg") <= -1) && (file.name.indexOf(".png") <= -1)) ? false : formData; // cancel all jpgs

 }

function onQueued(e, files) {
    console.log("Queued");
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      html += '<li data-index="' + files[i].index + '"><span class="content"><span class="file">' + files[i].name + '</span><span class="cancel">Cancel</span><span class="progress">Queued</span></span><span class="bar"></span></li>';
   }

  $(this).parents("form").find(".filelist.queue")
    .append(html);
 }

 function onStart(e, files) {

   $(this).parents("form").find(".filelist.queue")
    .find("li")
    .find(".progress").text("Waiting");
 }

 function onComplete(e) {
  console.log("Complete");
  // All done!
 }

function onFileStart(e, file) {
  console.log("File Start");
  $(this).parents("form").find(".filelist.queue")
    .find("li[data-index=" + file.index + "]")
    .find(".progress").text("0%");
 }

function onFileProgress(e, file, percent) {
  console.log("File Progress");
   var $file = $(this).parents("form").find(".filelist.queue").find("li[data-index=" + file.index + "]");

  $file.find(".progress").text(percent + "%")
  $file.find(".bar").css("width", percent + "%");
}

function onFileComplete(e, file, response) {
  console.log("File Complete");
  if (response.trim() === "" || response.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") > -1) {
     $(this).parents("form").find(".filelist.queue")
        .find("li[data-index=" + file.index + "]").addClass("error")
        .find(".progress").text(response.trim());
  } else {
    var $target = 
     $(this).parents("form").find(".filelist.queue").find("li[data-index=" + file.index + "]");
      $target.find(".file").text(file.name);
      $target.find(".progress").remove();
      $target.find(".cancel").remove();




$target.appendTo($(this).parents("form").find(".filelist.complete"));
    }
  }

   function onFileError(e, file, error) {
     console.log("File Error");
     $(this).parents("form").find(".filelist.queue")
    .find("li[data-index=" + file.index + "]").addClass("error")
    .find(".progress").text("Error: " + error);
  }
```

HTML where i used formstone control

---

```
<div class="uploadImage" style="height:100px;border:1px dashed #000;" data-upload-options='{"action":"<?php echo base_url();?>innovation/uploadImage","chunked":true}'></div>


<div class="uploadDocs" style="height:100px;border:1px dashed #000;" data-upload-options='{"action":"<?php echo base_url();?>innovation/uploadDocs","chunked":true}'></div>
```

Comment: You can use the option parameter `postData` to pass extra data like an name for a folder. Just refer to the [Documentation](https://formstone.it/components/upload/#options)

Comment: @CodyKL you mean something like $(".uploadImage").upload("start",postDate:{'userId':10}) ?

Comment: @CodyKL the folder name is something like a number, which will differ for each ajax response. the process is when user press submit button, it inserts some data using ajax giving a number as the response. after successful ajax response need to create a folder (name of the folder is the number get from response) and upload image or doc to the folder.

Comment: Regarding your first comment: Yes exactly in this way you pass extra data.
The folder creation is then server side (via PHP or whatever, I don't know which language you use on server side to process the form data).

Comment: @CodyKL when posting $(".uploadImage").upload("start",postData: {"ideaId":10}); like this not working, i can't get the data in **formData** variable. but passing  $(".uploadImage").upload({            
      maxSize: 1073741824,
      beforeSend: onBeforeSend,
      autoUpload: false,
      postData: {"ideaId":50}
    }); at the time of initialization is works. i have just hard coded the idea id here, actually it shoud come from the section where formstone called.

Comment: If this should come from the section where the form is called, then you have to provide the section to the plugin.

But to help you with that, you need to show more code.

Comment: @CodyKL $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'innovation/addProcess',
    dataType: "html",
    data: $('#add_innovation').serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
     
        var res = result.split("#");
     
     if (res[0] == 'success') {
      $(".uploadImage").upload("start",postData: {"ideaId":10});      
     } else {      
      showNotification('alert-danger', result);
     }

    }
   }); this is the code from where the Formstone called and in a library other functions are written. i want to pass the postData to that library.

Comment: Please provide your full code (HTML, JavaScript, PHP) in your start post).

Comment: @CodyKL just want a solution to get postData value send from ajax call, inside  onBeforeSend function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: base_url + 'innovation/addProcess',
 dataType: "html",
 data: $('#add_innovation').serialize(),
 success: function(result) {

    var res = result.split("#");
    if (res[0] == 'success') {
       $(".uploadImage").upload("defaults", {postData: {"ideaId":10}});
       $(".uploadImage").upload("start");
       $(".uploadDocs").upload("defaults", {postData: {"ideaId":10}});
       $(".uploadDocs").upload("start");
     } else {   
        showNotification('alert-danger', result);
     }

    },
     error: function(error) {
        console.log('error');
     }
 });
```

Before you call the method "start" you need to add the option "postData". As what I understand from the documentation the "start" method doesn't allow additional params.

Comment: If you get the `ideaId` in the response from your ajax call, then just add it like this: `{postData: {"ideaId":res[x]}}` (replace x with the number of the element which contains the ID).

Comment: have tried the code you mentioned, unfortunately, it's not working. formData.get("ideaId") this is how I tried to access the posted data, but not getting anything. the same will get data if I posted the data through formstone initialization.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see anywhere in your code the method `formData.get()` or the variable `formData`.

Comment: i have updated Formstone initialization section, where the data is accessing.

Answer (score 0):

CodyKL's solution works using the `defaults` method, or you can append extra params with the `beforeSend` callback:

```
// Var to store ID of inserted item
var resultId;

// Insertion AJAX
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(result) {
    // Get the id from the result
    resultId = result;

    // Start the upload
    $(".uploadImage").upload("start");
  },
  ...
});

// Initialize Upload
$(".uploadImage").upload({
  ...
  beforeSend: onBeforeSend,
  ...
});

// Modify upload form data 
function onBeforeSend(formData, file) {
  formData.append('ideaId', resultId); // add resultID obtained in insertion AJAX above to form data

  return formData; // Return modified formData
}
```

You should read up on how JS and the FormData API work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData.